# Deploy PHP project using git and free git repository

Tags: php, git, repository

How can I deploy an existing PHP project using Git and what is the best free git repository?

Comment: Is your question how to store php code in git or deploy it to the server with git?

Comment: both. I've used git only with rails project but never with php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [github](http://github.com) for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [free Git deploy tool](http://deploy.phpfog.com/) from PHP Fog.

Answer (score 0):

Github is generally considered best.

When I last did something like that, I simply SSH'd to the server did `git clone` and then had cron run a pull and update from my production "branch". You'll want to set up your git repository with your public key for the server, but instructions for that are pretty simple (I found the [Windows one](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) right off (scroll to the bottom), but it still works).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a private repo for free you should use BitBucket.

Check out this PHP script for deploying from Git repositories:

https://github.com/Lyquix/php-git-deploy